# How to ensure that unit test doctrine is attempting to load to the same database as dev?

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, symfony, doctrine

I would like to do some unit-testing in Symfony and am attempting to test something that already works, like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Tests\Api\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use App\Controller\Admin\ProductAdminController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

/**
 * Class ProductsAdminControllerTest
 * @package App\Tests\Api\Controller
 */
class ProductsAdminControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();
        static::$container = $kernel->getContainer();
        /*$this->_em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $this->_em->beginTransaction();*/
    }

    public function testSearchProductsEmpty()
    {
        $request = new Request([], [
            "product_name" => ""
        ]);
        $controller = new ProductsAdminController();
        $controller->setContainer(static::$container);
        $controller->getProducts($request);
        //$products = json_decode($controller->getProducts($request));
        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
    }
}
```

Of course this will be modified after I overcome my current problem, which is that no matter what I do, I get the error of

> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: An exception occurred in
>   driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'db_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Of course the database where my dev env is connecting has different credentials and I would like to ensure that my unit test is using the same credentials. How to achieve that?

Comment: overriding doctrine connection parameters in config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml ?

Comment: I use a SQLite database for the tests with the same structure as the real database. I created a Symfony Command that fills the main tables, and then I start testing

Comment: But I will call it a day now, I will only react tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: If it doesn't exist, create it as well, when you run the tests, symfony will use the one in the test directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to using different connection parameters for different environment, you can override configuration by creating file in config/packages/{env}/doctrine.yaml

For testing you can create config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        url: 'mysql://db_user4test:db_password4test@host4test:3306/dbname4test'
```

phpunit will use this configuration.

otherwise you can create a .env.test and override configuration ([Customizing Database URL / Environment Variables](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#customizing-database-url-environment-variables))

[EDIT] Another way as suggested by @LajosArpad is to add in phpunit.xml.dist:

```
<env name="DATABASE_URL" value="mysql://db_user4test:db_password4test@host4test:3306/dbname4test" />
```

See [Changing Database Settings for Functional Tests](https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/database.html#changing-database-settings-for-functional-tests)

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, creating an .env.test file, copied my dev settings into that, created a doctrine.yaml and tried with a correct url, I have also tried copying my dev settings from the other doctrine.yaml and so on, no luck at all, the error is the very same. So far it seems to me that it is way more difficult to do unit testing with Symfony than to work on features. I have solved an issue, spending some amount of time, but working on this unit test takes a ridiculously long time. I do not recommend Symfony and especially its unit tests to fellow programmers.

Comment: In vendor/symfony/maker-bundle/src/Test/MakerTestDetails.php we have the line $this
            ->addReplacement(
                '.env',
                'mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name',
                getenv('TEST_DATABASE_DSN')
            )
        ; which seems to be the problem here.

Comment: It's in a method called configureDatabase.

Comment: I received phpunit.xml.dist like this https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/phpunit/phpunit/4.7/phpunit.xml.dist